# MariaDB 10.0.28 strange log

Tags: php, mariadb

Yesterday I tried to load my website (around 13:00 PM), but when I tried to load all my tables where empty. I checked my mariadb log and I saw the follow:

```
# at 84030346
#170704 15:08:37 server id 1  end_log_pos 84030384 GTID 0-1-149236632
/*!100001 SET @@session.gtid_seq_no=149236632*//*!*/;
# at 84030384
#170704 15:08:37 server id 1  end_log_pos 84030513 Querythread_id=55526922exec_time=0error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1499173717/*!*/;
SET @@session.foreign_key_checks=0/*!*/;
SET @@session.sql_mode=524288/*!*/;
/*!\C utf8 *//*!*/;
SET @@session.character_set_client=33,@@session.collation_connection=33,@@session.collation_server=8/*!*/;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table1` /* generated by server */
/*!*/;
# at 84030513
#170704 15:08:37 server id 1  end_log_pos 84030551 GTID 0-1-149236633
/*!100001 SET @@session.gtid_seq_no=149236633*//*!*/;
# at 84030551
#170704 15:08:37 server id 1  end_log_pos 84030890 Querythread_id=55526922exec_time=0error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1499173717/*!*/;
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `column2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `column3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `column4` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!*/;
# at 84030890
#170704 15:08:37 server id 1  end_log_pos 84030928 GTID 0-1-149236634
/*!100001 SET @@session.gtid_seq_no=149236634*//*!*/;
/*!*/;
# at 84031400
#170704 15:08:37 server id 1  end_log_pos 84031438 GTID 0-1-149236635
/*!100001 SET @@session.gtid_seq_no=149236635*//*!*/;
# at 84031438
#170704 15:08:37 server id 1  end_log_pos 84031567 Querythread_id=55526922exec_time=0error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1499173717/*!*/;
SET @@session.foreign_key_checks=0/*!*/;
SET @@session.sql_mode=524288/*!*/;
/*!\C utf8 *//*!*/;
SET @@session.character_set_client=33,@@session.collation_connection=33,@@session.collation_server=8/*!*/;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `table2` /* generated by server */
/*!*/;
# at 84031567
#170704 15:08:37 server id 1  end_log_pos 84031605 GTID 0-1-149236636
/*!100001 SET @@session.gtid_seq_no=149236636*//*!*/;
# at 84031605
#170704 15:08:37 server id 1  end_log_pos 84032593 Querythread_id=55526922exec_time=0error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1499173717/*!*/;
CREATE TABLE `table2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `column1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `column2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `column3` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `column4` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`),
  KEY `column1` (`column1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
/*!*/;
# at 84032593
#170704 15:08:37 server id 1  end_log_pos 84032631 GTID 0-1-149236637
/*!100001 SET @@session.gtid_seq_no=149236637*//*!*/;
```

The things I think that's wrong:

- doesn't start with `BEGIN` and end with `COMMIT`
- it has `/* generated by server */` after a drop
- it creates the same table after the drop

What can this be, that the log of mariadb doesn't start with `BEGIN` and ends with `COMMIT`?

- a user who manual entered the drop table?
- a script that's executed?

Comment: It's not a query log, it's a binary log. There is nothing particularly suspicious about it, except that it's of July 4th, so, given your described time line, it's most likely irrelevant to the problem that you are having.

Comment: And what means `/* generated by server */` @elenst?

Comment: For the purpose of investigating this problem, it means nothing. MariaDB (and MySQL) write `DROP TABLE` in the binary log in this fashion, as a part of the logic dealing with temporary tables and binlog formats. All in all, it will be logged so if you run a perfectly normal `DROP TABLE`  or `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` statement.